# Is there a way to share files in two different projects without using absolute path?

Tags: python

In python, I have a text file that needs to be shared in ProjectB and ProjectA. Let's say I put 'data.txt' into ProjectB. And ProjectB and ProjectA are under the same parent directory, namely:

```
ProjectA
  test_data.py

ProjectB
   data.txt
```

Now I want to open 'data.txt' in ProjectA. Is there a way to reach it from ProjectA without using absolute path?

Comment: absolute or relative path should work,

Comment: Did you try `with open('../ProjectB/data.txt', 'r') as foo:`?

Comment: @singrium, does this work? I will try.

Comment: Yes it's possible. You can use the ../ notation to up or / to  down inside arborescence.

Comment: Do both projects really need to be using the exact same file? Because if they only need the same data, then you might be able to use an outside tool to keep things synced up. For instance, git submodules would let you put `data.txt` in its own repository, and then check out a copy of that repo inside each of `ProjectA` and `ProjectB`.

Comment: @Blckknght, that's a good idea too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a python file (let's name it open_data.py) in ProjectA and put the following line in it then run it.

```
with open('../ProjectB/data.txt', 'r') as foo:
    data = foo.read()
    print(data)
```

Here is the tree of the folders as you described:

```
Parent_Folder
├── ProjectA
│   └── open_data.py
└── ProjectB
    └── data.txt
```

After runnin open_data.py from ProjectA, you'll get the content data.txt which exists in ProjectB

```
~$ cd Parent_Folder/ProjectA/
~/Parent_Folder/ProjectA$ python3 open_data.py 
This is data.txt from ProjectB
```

Comment: You don't need `foo.close()` when you're using a `with` statement for the file. It will be closed automatically!